# snprintf in signal handler creates segmentation fault if started with valgrind

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, printf, valgrind

This very simple C program gives me a segmentation fault when running it with `valgrind`.
Its runs fine when started normal.
It crashes when you send the USR1 signal to the process.

The problem seems to be the way `snprintf` handles the formatting of the float value, because it works fine if you use a string (`%s`) or int (`%d`) format parameter.

P.S. I know you you shouldn't call any printf family function inside a signal handler, but still why does it only crash with `valgrind`.

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <signal.h>

    void sig_usr1(int sig) {
            char buf[128];
            snprintf(buf, sizeof(buf), "%f", 1.0);
    }

    int main(int argc, char **argv) {
            (void) signal(SIGUSR1, sig_usr1);
            while(1);
    }
```

Comment: Is `snprintf` even safe to use in a signal handler?

Comment: @mu here is a list with signal safe posix functions: https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/seccode/SIG30-C.+Call+only+asynchronous-safe+functions+within+signal+handlers

Comment: @RedX: Thank you: "...asynchronous-safe in OpenBSD but "probably not on other systems," including snprintf(),...". This [list](http://linux.die.net/man/2/signal) doesn't mention `snprintf` either.

Comment: Do you have a SEGV of your program (`vcore` file is generated) or of the valgrind itself (`core` file is generated)? Please, get an backtrace from vcore file using gdb: `gdb yourprogram vcore.XXXXX`; then `bt`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a valgrind bug.  It calls your signal handler with a stack that is not 16-byte aligned as required by the ABI.  On x86_64, floating point arguments are passed in XMM registers which can only be stored at addresses that are 16-byte aligned.  You can work around the problem by compiling for 32-bit (`gcc -m32`).

Comment: I realize this is old--but do you know if there's a link to the bug report?

Comment: @villapx: This was fixed in 2012.  For Linux it was: https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=280114  For OS X it was fixed as part of: https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=254646

Comment: Interesting--the OP's exact code still fails for me with a seg fault on Valgrind 3.8.1 (Linux 2.6.32, x86_64, GCC 4.4.7)

Comment: @villapx: The first release with the Linux fix (bug 280114) was 3.9.0.  The OS X fix (bug 254646) was in 3.8.0.  The current version is 3.11.0.

Answer (score 4):

As [cnicutar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/714501/cnicutar) notes, valgrind may have an effect on anything timing related and signal handlers would certainly qualify.

I don't think `snprintf` is safe to use in a signal handler so it might be working in the non-valgrind case solely by accident and then valgrind comes in, changes the timing, and you get the flaming death that you were risking without valigrind.

I found a list of functions that are safe in signal handlers (according to POSIX.1-2003 ) here:

> http://linux.die.net/man/2/signal

Yes, the `linux.die.net` man pages are a bit out of date but the list here (thanks to [RedX](https://stackoverflow.com/users/551045/redx) for finding this one):

> https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/seccode/SIG30-C.+Call+only+asynchronous-safe+functions+within+signal+handlers

doesn't mention `snprintf` either except in the context of OpenBSD where it say:

> ... asynchronous-safe in OpenBSD but "probably not on other systems," including snprintf(), ...

so the implication is that `snprintf` is not, in general, safe in a signal handler.

And, thanks to [Nemo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/768469/nemo), we have an authoritative list of functions that are safe for use in signal handlers:

> http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/V2_chap02.html#tag_15_04_03

Start at that link and search down for `_Exit` and you'll see the list; then you'll see that `snprintf` is not on the list.

Also, I remember using `write()` in a signal handler because `fprintf` wasn't safe for a signal handler but that was a long time ago.

I don't have a copy of the relevant standard so I can't back this up with anything really authoritative but I thought I'd mention it anyway.

Comment: The canonical list is in [section 2.4.3 of the POSIX spec](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/V2_chap02.html#tag_15_04_03).  (Scroll down a little.)

Comment: @Nemo: Thanks, I was having trouble finding an authoritative reference. I knew `snprintf` wasn't on the list but "know" and "prove" are rather different.

Answer (score 4):

From manual: http://www.network-theory.co.uk/docs/valgrind/valgrind_27.html and http://www.network-theory.co.uk/docs/valgrind/valgrind_24.html

> Valgrind's signal simulation is not as robust as it could be. Basic POSIX-compliant sigaction and sigprocmask functionality is supplied, but it's conceivable that things could go badly awry if you do weird things with signals. Workaround: don't. Programs that do non-POSIX signal tricks are in any case inherently unportable, so should be avoided if possible.

So, snprintf in signal handler is not a POSIX-allowed signal trick and valgrind has a right to brick your programs.

Why snprintf is not signal-safe?

The glibc manual says: http://www.gnu.org/software/hello/manual/libc/Nonreentrancy.html

> If a function uses and modifies an object that you supply, then it is potentially non-reentrant; two calls can interfere if they use the same object.
>
> This case arises when you do I/O using streams. Suppose that the signal handler prints a message with fprintf. Suppose that the program was in the middle of an fprintf call using the same stream when the signal was delivered. Both the signal handler's message and the program's data could be corrupted, because both calls operate on the same data structure—the stream itself.
>
> However, if you know that the stream that the handler uses cannot possibly be used by the program at a time when signals can arrive, then you are safe. It is no problem if the program uses some other stream.

You can say that s*printf* are not on streams, but on strings. But internally, glibc's snprintf does work on special stream:

ftp://sources.redhat.com/pub/glibc/snapshots/glibc-latest.tar.bz2/glibc-20090518/libio/vsnprintf.c

```
int
_IO_vsnprintf (string, maxlen, format, args)
{
  _IO_strnfile sf; // <<-- FILE*-like descriptor
```

The `%f` output code in glibc also has a malloc call inside it:

ftp://sources.redhat.com/pub/glibc/snapshots/glibc-latest.tar.bz2/glibc-20090518/stdio-common/printf_fp.c

```
/* Allocate buffer for output.  We need two more because while rounding
   it is possible that we need two more characters in front of all the
   other output.  If the amount of memory we have to allocate is too
   large use `malloc' instead of `alloca'.  */
size_t wbuffer_to_alloc = (2 + (size_t) chars_needed) * sizeof (wchar_t);
buffer_malloced = ! __libc_use_alloca (chars_needed * 2 * sizeof (wchar_t));
if (__builtin_expect (buffer_malloced, 0))
  {
    wbuffer = (wchar_t *) malloc (wbuffer_to_alloc);
    if (wbuffer == NULL)
      /* Signal an error to the caller.  */
      return -1;
  }
else
  wbuffer = (wchar_t *) alloca (wbuffer_to_alloc);
```

Answer (score 2):

Valgrind slightly changes the timings in your program.

Have a loot at the [FAQ](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/faq.html#faq.crashes).

> My program **crashes normally, but doesn't under Valgrind, or vice
>   versa**. What's happening?
>
> When a program runs under Valgrind, its environment is slightly
>   different to when it runs natively.
>   Most of the time this doesn't make any difference, but it can,
>   particularly if your program is buggy.

Comment: but why changed timings leads to segv?